# Laravel Changing Migration field Float to Double

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3, laravel-migrations

I want to create a table with a float column.

```
$table->float('TaxRate',5,5)->default(0.00000);
```

But Mysql Taking this as a DOUBLE.

[image]

How this working ?.

Answer (score 3):

It because `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar` converts `float` into `double`. I don't know the reason why they enforce it to use `double`.

Overriding the `MySqlGrammar` will be troublesome, since you will have to override more classes.

You can use raw mysql query to create table like below

```
public function up() {
    DB::unprepared('CREATE TABLE `temp`(
        `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `tax_rate` FLOAT(5, 5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000,
        ...
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
    );
}
```